# Concatenating a variable with other text using Rythm

Tags: java, template-engine, templating, rythm

I am using the Rythm templating engine. I have a variable and I want to 'concatenate' it with other text without any spaces. I don't know how to delimit my variable name and the surrounding text - Rythm tries to resolve both the variable name and the extra text as a single expression.

Here is an example:

```
@args String who
Hello @whoextra
```

I get the following error when trying it on [http://fiddle.rythmengine.org](http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/):

```
org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: whoextra cannot be resolved to a variable
```

If 'who' has the value 'World', what I want to print is:

```
Hello Worldextra
```

I can achieve this with:

```
@args String who
Hello @who.raw()extra
```

But it seems a bit verbose, especially if I use it in many places.

Is there a better way to delimit my expressions in Rythm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `(` and `)` to separate:

```
@args String who
Hello @(who)extra
```

For more information about expression in Rythm template, checkout http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#expression